# Automate python test with testlink and hudson

Tags: python, automated-tests, hudson, testlink

I want to run automated test on my python script using Hudson and testlink. I configured Hudson with my testlink server but the test results are always "`not run`". Do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to do it : 
I used testLink-API-Python-client.